# ¿Por qué razón no me funciona el overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy aprendiendo CSS y tengo este código:

```css
.poster {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.poster img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*padding: 10px 0;*/
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.poster:hover .caption {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="poster">
  <img class="img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/57/21/ee/5721eee76f2677a139062eb906761f09.jpg" alt="" />
  <p class="caption">Star Wars - Pelicula de 1970</p>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, el `overflow:hidden` no funciona ya que no oculta completamente el párrafo para que se pueda lograr la animación.

Sé que para que funcione y se oculte un objeto posicionado en ABSOLUTE su acentro tiene que ser RELATIVE, pero aun asi no funciona.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que estás aplicando el `overflow:hidden` al elemento incorrecto. No es el párrafo el elemento cuyo contenido sobrante debe estar oculto, es su padre (.poster). Entonces, haz que .poster tenga `overflow:hidden` y eso solucionará el problema:

```css
.poster {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.poster img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*padding: 10px 0;*/
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.poster:hover .caption {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="poster">
  <img class="img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/57/21/ee/5721eee76f2677a139062eb906761f09.jpg" alt="" />
  <p class="caption">Star Wars - Pelicula de 1970</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Fue un error tonto pero ya se me quedara grabado. :D